# I can't retrieve my data from request AJAX in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Here the code of my Blade and it works and send the request, but I can't retrieve the data from the AJAX.

**Javascript**

```
function addUser() {
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'addUser',
        data: {name:name,email:email,password:password,},
        success:function(data) {
            $("#msg").html(data.msg);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $msg=User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt( $request->password),
    ]);
    return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
 }
```

Comment: can you show the result `dd($request->all())`?

Comment: What exactly happens? You send the request but it's denied or you send the request and get data back but don't know how to parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

`processData` by default is set to `true` and assumes that the data passed is an object, setting it to `false` will prevent the default parse behavior - which you do not want! This may be good in cases where want to send raw JSON, but this is different to form data.

`contentType` is also passed as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. If you set `contentType` to `false`, you are not setting any content header! So by removing both values you will have the correct defaults to successfully send the ajax call.